# Get `__typename` from interface

Tags: typescript, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a `ts` interface (for an `apollo-client@v2` `gql` query) that has a `__typename` property. In the existing codebase there is a lot of "rehydration" of data object that re-adds the `__typename` type of interfaces in a "magic string" way. I am wondering if there is a way to reference a string type via `ts` or a way to avoid doing this via the existing type or cache systems.

An example (generated) interface:

```
export interface SomeNode {
  __typename: "SomeNode";
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

Is there a way to get the "SomeNode" as a value and as a type?

```
const newObject: SomeNode = {
  __typename: string(NewNode.__typename) as NewNode.__typename,
  id: 'some value',
  name: 'some name'
}
```

Currently we do this:

```
const newObject: SomeNode = {
  __typename: "NewNode" as "NewNode",
  id: 'some value',
  name: 'some name'
}
```

> This is a simplified example and the usage does seem weird. But I am looking for a way to do this specific thing. Without this, we end up recreating the already generated types throughout our codebase.